# Keep unique scores in each row of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have the following data frame in R, which have duplicated characters in each row.

```
i01 A   A   A   A   A   A
i02 B   C   D   B   C   D
i03 E   F   E   F   E   F
i04 G   G   G   G   G   G
i05 H   I   J   K   L   M
i06 N   O   P   N   O   P
```

I want to keep only the unique score in each row in the entire data frame, and replace the duplicate scores either by a blank or NA. Something like this:

```
i01 A   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
i02 B   C   D   NA  NA  NA
i03 E   F   NA  NA  NA  NA
i04 G   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
i05 H   I   J   K   L   M
i06 N   O   P   NA  NA  NA
```

I am trying by simply using unique function in the entire data frame but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,function(x) ifelse(duplicated(x),NA,x))),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I see this is almost identical to @akrun's solution, only I used ifelse to his replace. same same...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `duplicated` to assign `NA` for those duplicates in a row

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("i01", "i02", "i03", "i04", "i05", "i06"
), v1 = c("A", "B", "E", "G", "H", "N"), v2 = c("A", "C", "F", 
"G", "I", "O"), v3 = c("A", "D", "E", "G", "J", "P"), v4 = c("A", 
 "B", "F", "G", "K", "N"), v5 = c("A", "C", "E", "G", "L", "O"
 ), v6 = c("A", "D", "F", "G", "M", "P")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```